# Что означает четвёртая колонка в выводе команды «ls -l»?

Tags: windows, bash, консоль

Что означает набор цифр (выделил цветом). 
Данные появляются после команды `ls -al`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как сказать командной строке, чтобы появилась "шапка" на выводимыми данными?

Comment: Вероятно, это gid - id группы. Видимо группы не существует)

Comment: [Похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45696607/2110496)

Comment: текст лучше текстом прилагается вивопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это gid - id группы.

Видимо группы не существует.
Вы можете убедиться в этом в `/etc/group`.
Либо добавить её туда.
Либо сменить группу пользователю, но уже созданные им файлы сохранят id старой группы.

Команда `id` покажет Вам текущую основную группу пользователя и список дополнительных.

Comment: почему решили что группы не существует? как посмотреть /etc/group ?

Comment: `cat /etc/group` Потому что иначе бы выводилось её имя.

Comment: Вообще, у Вас там какая-то оболочка, не факт, что полноценный linux. Я не могу быть ни в чём уверен, глядя на виндовое окошко. =)

Comment: пишет что /etc/group не существует

Comment: Видимо кто-то посчитал, что группы не нужны ™

Comment: всё же, gid присутствует. а группы нет. как же так

Comment: Вероятно группа где-то была, просто в конкретной этой оболочке /etc/group не проброшен/не залинковался/не смонтировался/не нужен...

Comment: @DmitryNikitin Попробуйте `getent group`. А по поводу имени, его может не существовать, система работает с числами (вы так же можете поудалять базу пользователей, но оставить их файлы).